# Button in CMS page that links to registering page

Tags: magento-1.7, url, magento-community, register, cms-pages

I am using Magento 1.7. I am designing a CMS page through the WYSIWYG editor in the Admin->CMS->Pages section, with the tool 'Edit HTML source'. I need to **add a button in the CMS page** that links to the registration page.

I added the following to the HTML code of my page:

```
<form action="{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}/index.php/es/customer/account/create/">
    <input type="submit" value="Go to registering page" />
</form>
```

But it's not working. I tried to use single (") quotations and normal quotations (') but it's not working anyway.

What is the proper way to define the URL in this case? Is there a better way to insert this button?

Comment: Why don't add a link instead of a button. `<a href="{{store url="customer/account/create"}}" >Go to registering page</a>`

Comment: I have a design that requires a button. I have the code for the button in app/design/frontend/default/custom_theme/persistent/customer/form/register, but as this is a CMS page I can't include PHP code in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know why your code is not working, but try below code instead

```
<form action="{{store url='customer/account/create'}}">
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Go to registering page" />
</form>
```

Comment: @LeCodeur You are always welcome